# Son created an account using a junk email

Tags: pokemon-go

When my son originally created his POkemon Go account he asked for my email address which I refused. He forgot his, so he created a junk email account. Now that the app was upgraded, my son can't play because all updates are being done through an gmail account he can't access it because he does not remember the password.  I tried to create the email address but someone is already using it.  Is there a way to transfer his Pokemon Go to a new gmail account or is he out of luck.

Comment: What do you mean with fictional account? Either he created a new Gmail account or not. If he created a new Gmail account he should also have created the password for it.

Comment: I don't think he created a gmail account, I think he just typed in a random one or one that did not exist (at least under his name)

Comment: You can't just create a Pokemon Go account with only an email address. You would have to be logged in which would require a password.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to sign into the app, you can go into settings and logout of that account to log into another one. You will lose your account data doing this. If you cannot log into the app, and get stuck at the loading screen (with the Gyrados) there is a chance for it to have a "Sign Out" button right in the center. That will allow you to get out and sign in with an email address/account you control.

The problem is that your son effectively created his account under someone else's name, and now that account is theirs and he will not be able to get it back. You'll need to create a new account, tied to an email you already have. Either your son will need to remember his email account or create a new one before signing into it in the game. Unfortunately he has no other options.